# Textbox values as an array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Trying to store textbox values into different arrays. In my jQuery code array *textA* stores the textbox values of 'textA' and array *textB* must store the values of 'textB'. In the result, *textB* is containing the values of textbox 'textA' as well. As a result, I want only the values of textbox 'textB' in the array *textB*.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  textA = textB = [];
 
  $('button').click(function(){
   $('input[name^=textA]').each(function(){
    textA.push($(this).val()); 
    $('span#textA').text(textA);
   });
 
   $('input[name^=textB]').each(function(){
    textB.push($(this).val());
    $('span#textB').text(textB);
   });
 textA = textB = [];
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="textA" placeholder="Enter text A">
<input type="text" name="textA" placeholder="Enter text A"></br>
<input type="text" name="textB" placeholder="Enter text B">
<input type="text" name="textB" placeholder="Enter text B"></br>
<button>
Click
</button></br>
<span id="textA"></span></br>
<span id="textB"></span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign as   seperately `textA = []; textB = [];`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  textA = [];
  textB = [];
 
  $('button').click(function(){
   $('input[name^=textA]').each(function(){
    textA.push($(this).val()); 
    $('span#textA').text(textA);
   });
 
   $('input[name^=textB]').each(function(){
    textB.push($(this).val());
    $('span#textB').text(textB);
   });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="textA" placeholder="Enter text A">
<input type="text" name="textA" placeholder="Enter text A"></br>
<input type="text" name="textB" placeholder="Enter text B">
<input type="text" name="textB" placeholder="Enter text B"></br>
<button>
Click
</button></br>
<span id="textA"></span></br>
<span id="textB"></span>
```